# How do I return a scalar variable from a select statement

Tags: sql

I am altering a table by adding a new column, this column must have a default value taken from  a single entry in another table

```
ALTER TABLE Bonus_Profile 
ADD Orgunit varchar(50) NOT NULL
DEFAULT (select top 1 OrgUnit from OrgUnits where ReportTo is null)
```

The above statement gives `Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.` as and error

What should be used to get a scalar variable of `OrgUnit`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Top without order by isn't deterministic. If SQL Server you can't use a subquery there but can set a scalar UDF as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parameterless scalar function first

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReturnOrgUnit ()

RETURNS VARCHAR(50)   

BEGIN

  Declare @orgUnit varchar(50)

  Select TOP 1 @orgUnit= OrgUnit from OrgUnits where ReportTo is null

  Return @orgUnit
END
```

Then you can use above udf in alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE Bonus_Profile 
ADD Orgunit varchar(50) NOT NULL
DEFAULT (ReturnOrgUnit())
```